# Resources loaded from target/test-classes on first run after build

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Whenever I do a maven clean install on my project and then run the application from IntelliJ IDEA, the resources are wrongly loaded from target/test-classes instead of target/classes. This only happens on first run, after I stop and restart the application, the files are loaded correctly from target/classes everytime, until I do a new maven clean install.

What could cause this behavior? Isn't target/test-classes only supposed to be used during test phase?

EDIT 1: Add snippet of resources build from pom

```
         <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources-filtered</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
           </build>
```

Comment: Please have a look in your pom to see if any of the defaults regarding paths are overridden

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added a snippet showing the resource build in the pom

Comment: When running after a maven clean install and pressing run, IDEA also builds and writes classes before the first run. Maybe I have IDEA configured wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<testresources>` to the `<build>` node of the maven POM, like this:

```
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
      </testResource>
     </testResources>
```

Comment: @Mr Lister if the answer works for you, please upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After installing the new 2017 update for IntelliJ today, the issue disappeared and resources are loaded from the correct folder on first run.